# Cleanest way of parsing in a text file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader

Then splitting each line into three parts and placing those parts into individual `String[] arrays`?

So currently i am importing the  the file via `BufferedReader`/`FileReader`, adding each line to a `ArrayList<String>`. That looks like:

```
     String line;

     ArrayList<String> thing = new ArrayList<String>();
     
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "file.txt"));    
     
     while (true) {   
         line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            thing.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
```

The contents of each is then being parsed into a `String[] array` in a basic for-loop.

```
       String[] array = new String[thing.size()];
       for(i=0;i<thing.size();i++) {
            array[i] = thing.get(i)
        }
```

and that is as far as i have gotten so far.

The data being imported is formatted as follows:

> Euro (EUR), 1.359, €
>
> US Dollars (USD), 1.34, $

I understand that `split` along with a regex similar to `\\s*,\\s*` would probably be used to split the string into its various components, but as far as that i have zero idea.

Question: how would i go about splitting tthe string up further.

For example, placing each first part of the string into an array called `currency`, each second part of the string into an array called `factor`, so and so forth.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're asking. You have given your code so far but what do you want this code to do?

Comment: The question is at the top. I want to be able to split the String into three parts, and place each of those parts into it's one of three arrays (one for the first part, one for second party and one for third part) - for ease later on down the line. @GBlodgett - sorry if that wasn't clear enough

Comment: Meet `toArray()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])

Comment: @tevemadar I don't see how `List::toArray` would help. I'd suggest splitting each line at `,` with `String::split`. The result should be an Array with the three elements of your CSV String (I assume what you're reading is a CSV).

Comment: @dstlny Yes but how do you want to split them? Could you give an example output with your example? Are you trying to split on the comma?

Comment: Sure. Example below. The string `Euro (EUR), 1.359, €` from the `ArrayList` would be split as follows. Each subsequent string would be split the same, all into corresponding arrays

`currencyArray[0] -> Euro (EUR)`
`factorArray[0] -> 1.359`
`symbolArray[0] -> €` @GBlodgett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split(",")` inside for loop to split each String to additional three parts and then add them to the appropriate array:

```
        List<String> thing = new ArrayList<>();
        thing.add("Euro (EUR), 1.359, €");

        String[] currency = new String[thing.size()];
        String[] factor = new String[thing.size()];
        String[] sign = new String[thing.size()];

        for(int i=0;i<thing.size();i++) {
            String parts[] = thing.get(i).split(",");
            currency[i] = parts[0];
            factor[i] =  parts[1];
            sign[i] =  parts[2];
        }

        System.out.println(currency[0] + " " + factor[0] + " " + sign[0]);
```

Outpt:

Euro (EUR)  1.359  €

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split your lines with `\s*,\s*` (and not `+` because it requires at least one space), then store the 3 parts in 3 lists. This option is easier compare to read the file to store each line and then iterate over the `List` to split and add to `arrays` ([**`Other option code`**](https://ideone.com/OX2ff4)).

You can do all of it in the loop which reads the file :

```
String line;
String[] lineSplit;

ArrayList<String> currencyList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> factorList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> symbolList = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineSplit = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        if (lineSplit.length == 3) {
            currencyList.add(lineSplit[0]);
            factorList.add(lineSplit[1]);
            symbolList.add(lineSplit[2]);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you need arrays at the end just :

```
String[] currency = currencyList.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] factor = factorList.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] symbol = symbolList.toArray(new String[0]);
```